# Update datagrid in WPF window (not MainWindow) from another one. *Without using MVVM*

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid, window

I have a **Window1** which contains a datagrid that is filled with MYSQL Database when **Window1** is loaded, but to make an update there's this **Window2** that contains textboxes in order to save the new information in MYSQL Database.
I can update the information after I open and close **Window2** as I show below:

```
Window2.ShowDialog();

//refreshing datagrid

Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.AppStarting;
dtCustomers = AdminDB.Get_Table("SELECT id, name FROM engcustomers", db.MySqlCon);
dataGrid.DataContext = dtCustomers;
MessageBox.Show("The information has been updated correctly");
Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
```

And this works perfectly, the issue comes when in **Window2** I press the button "Cancel" because I do not want to update anything, but due to my code, the query is executed anyway. 
That's why I need your support/help to update the datagrid in **Window1** from **Window2**.

Could you pleeease help me?

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ShowDialog()` method returns a `bool?` that you can set in the `Window2` before you close it and then use to determine whether the operation was cancelled in `Window1`:

```
bool? cancelled = Window2.ShowDialog();

if (cancelled != true)
{
    //refreshing datagrid

    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.AppStarting;
    dtCustomers = AdminDB.Get_Table("SELECT id, name FROM engcustomers", db.MySqlCon);
    dataGrid.DataContext = dtCustomers;
    MessageBox.Show("The information has been updated correctly");
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

**Window2:**

```
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
    Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use "bool? cancelled = Window2.ShowDialog();" but it threw me an error, so I used this one instead:

if (Window2.DialogResult != true)

THANK YOU SO MUCH! ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐